# Play inexplicably reports class "already defined"

Tags: playframework

I basically started with the tutorial and the hello world example.  Now I'm stuck where when I try to run the BasicTest (right click the test and run style), it gives me this:

play.exceptions.CompilationException: The type ApplicationTest is already defined

I don't know what this means.  I'm not trying to run that test and I can't see how it's relevant to what I'm doing.  I realize Play auto compiles stuff but even then I don't see why I'm getting this error.  I tried doing a "play clean", I've tried deleting the compiled ApplicationTest class but nothing seems to matter.

Any ideas how to get past this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't right-click and run the test.  From the command-line, type

```
play test
```

then go to http://localhost:9000/@tests

Comment: That works but it's odd that you cannot just right-click and run a unit test like in most java apps.  It's especially inconvenient since the tests are started on the same port so you have to kill the regular server just to run tests which goes counter to the whole notion of not having to restart your server when you use Play.

Comment: If you want the test mode to run on a different port, add `%test.http.port=9001` or whatever different port you want in your application.conf file. This means you can have both normal and test mode running simultaneously

Comment: Also, when the app is running in test mode, you can also see the app. Type `play test` then go to http://localhost:9000